# Check assumptions in generalized linear model binomial family

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, assumptions

I have the following dataset

```
'data.frame':   768 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Trattamento: Factor w/ 4 levels "CONTROLLO","LIDAR",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Risposta   : num  0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I have four treatments (Trattamento) and a response variable (Risposta) that is binomial.
I want to check whether the treatments have an effect on my response variable.
I applied the following model and obtained the following results:

```
    model <- glm(Risposta ~ Trattamento,
                     data = data,
                     family = binomial(link = "logit"))
Call:
glm(formula = Risposta ~ Trattamento, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = data)

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           0.1252     0.1446   0.865   0.3868    
TrattamentoLIDAR     -0.9136     0.2125  -4.299 1.71e-05 ***
TrattamentoRECUPERO  -1.2238     0.2207  -5.546 2.92e-08 ***
TrattamentoSTANDARD  -0.4402     0.2056  -2.141   0.0322 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1019.18  on 767  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  981.31  on 764  degrees of freedom
AIC: 989.31

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

My interpretation here is that there are significant effects of treatment respect to my response variable. Thus I applied the following post-hoc test:

```
tukey_results <- glht(model, linfct = mcp(Trattamento = "Tukey"))

 Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glm(formula = Risposta ~ Trattamento, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
LIDAR - CONTROLLO == 0     -0.9136     0.2125  -4.299  < 0.001 ***
RECUPERO - CONTROLLO == 0  -1.2238     0.2207  -5.546  < 0.001 ***
STANDARD - CONTROLLO == 0  -0.4402     0.2056  -2.141  0.13992    
RECUPERO - LIDAR == 0      -0.3102     0.2281  -1.360  0.52432    
STANDARD - LIDAR == 0       0.4734     0.2135   2.217  0.11853    
STANDARD - RECUPERO == 0    0.7835     0.2217   3.535  0.00214 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

I wanted to check that the main assumptions of the GLM are satisfied using this code:

```
plot(model, which = 1)
plot(residuals(model), pch = 16, main = "Residuals Plot")
qqnorm(residuals(model))
qqline(residuals(model))
```

Can you help me interpreting the graphs that I obtained?:
[image: Residuals vs fitted]
[image: Residuals plot]
[image: Q-Q plot]

Comment: If the treatments are categorical and they are the only variables in the model, then the only real assumption is that the observations are iid. Your model is basically estimating the risk of the outcome for each treatment; no different than just computing the mean in each treatment group.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that I can also apply a simpler test? If yes, which one might be suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the treatments are categorical, your model as it stands looks like

$$ \log \left( \dfrac{p_i}{1-p_i} \right) = \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1} \beta_i \mathbb{I}(trt_i = i)   $$

Essentially, you're estimating one mean for each treatment.  The mean for treatment $i$ on the log odds scale is then $$\beta_0 + \beta_i$$

So far as assumptions go, the only things you are assuming are:

- The data are iid
- The likelihood is binomial

There are no other assumptions, e.g about linearity of the conditional log odds in a specific variable, to check.  Even if there were other assumptions to check, those residual plots are not the ones to look at.

Because your model is so simple, you could get away with just comparing the risk difference between groups (i.e. doing a test of proportion between all treatments).  The two approaches would be equivalent.

Comment: *There are no other assumptions, e.g about linearity of the conditional log odds in a specific variable, to check. Even if there were other assumptions to check, those residual plots are not the ones to look at.*---What should the check then? I think that is the essence of OP's question.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand If the data are binomial, there is nothing to check.  The iid assumption can't be checked with data, one has to bring their domain knowledge to the problem.  The binomial likelihood is an assumption, but if the data are binary I think its safe to make this.

My point here is that OP might as well group by treatment and estimate the mean  in each group. The analysis doesn't necessitate logistic regression, and hence there are not many assumptions being made.

Comment: If OP wants to know what kind of diagnostic plots to make, I think your answer is useful.

Comment: I can see your point now. Your logic makes sense (+1 btw).

Comment: Thank you. So as far as I understood I can make a group mean between the zeros and ones within each treatment and compare the means among treatments. Which mean comparison approach should be more appropriate with the type of data I have?

Comment: @GiorgioS both methods are equivalent

Comment: I have applied a simple chi-square test and I came up with the same significances

Comment: @GiorgioS  The chi-square should be approximately the same as the likelihood ratio test for logistic regression, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Standard residual plots tend to not be very useful for logistic regressions or other forms of GLMs. I would instead run some simulated residuals and see if their output looks normal. The `DHarma` package is great for this and has a [useful vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) for learning how to run them on a number of generalized linear and additive models.